# AWS PinPoint Send Voice C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to develop a Voice Notification using C# (.NET) using AWS PinPoint. AWS Provides the code template for this project for JAVA however I have not seen anywhere online for a code template in C# (.NET).

I understand I can create a java file and create a DDL and use in C#, however not a fan of this method.

Would anyone have any other tips or maybe themselves have developed this in C#.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the link which you mentioned to the docs please.

Comment: @PhilippS.  No worries, I was already able to figure it out.